# When trying to invoke a rest api to upload multipart file Getting error No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I am trying to consume a rest api to upload a Multipart file. I have set MultipartFile in UploadFIleObject and I am sending the same to rest api. However when trying to invoke a rest API as below, I am getting error  No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

```
public class UploadFileObject implements Serializable{

  MultipartFile file;

//getters and setters
}

public void uploadFile() {

Path path = Paths.get("C:/Accounts.txt");
byte[] content = null;

try{
    content =  Files.readAllBytes(path);   
} catch(final IOException e){
}

MultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("ABC.txt","ABC.txt","text/plain", content);
    
UploadFileObject obj = new UploadFileObject();
obj.setFile(file)

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.set(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.setContentType("Accept", Mediatype.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
headers.setContentType("Content-type", Mediatype.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(obj, headers);

String result = getRestTemplate().postForEntity("url", requestEntity, String.class);

}
```

in application.yml

I have set

```
spring.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans: false
```

and in pom.xml I have below of version 2.12.3

```
jackson-annotation
jackson-core
jackson-databind
jackson-dataformat
jackson-dataformat-xml
}
```

Comment: this may be a duplicate, not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212246/no-serializer-found-for-class-java-io-bytearrayinputstream

Comment: no this has not worked for me

Comment: Please show us the complete stacktrace so that we can understand where the serialization is occurring.